# Castle.TypedFactory.DefaultInterfaceFactoryComponentSelector could not be resolved

Tags: castle-windsor

I am following [example by José F. Romaniello](http://joseoncode.com/2011/03/03/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps/) on session management with NHibernate. It's a very good article, however I'm struggling with it having very little experience with NHibernate, Windsor and MVC.

I am trying to re-create NHibernateInstaller, however encountering the following error: `Component Castle.TypedFactory.DefaultInterfaceFactoryComponentSelector could not be resolved. Make sure you didn't misspell the name, and that component is registered.`

In the sample project provided this error does not crop up, even though the installer is identical and Google does not come up with any results (which is very unusual). What causes this and how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

it seems a problem with the TypedFactoryFacility... are you doing this?

```
kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
```

before running all the installers?

Comment: Somebody needed to point out the obvious - thank you. I did do this, but only after inline declaration and installation!

Comment: Yep, got the same issue while following the entry (http://joseoncode.com/2011/03/07/create-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-windsor-and-nhibernate-at-the-speed-of-nuget/). Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

uncomment the following code in Bootstrapper.cs file.

container.AddFacility();

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I created my own implementation of `ITypedFactoryComponentSelector`, **but forgot to register the selector itself.**

There was no indication this was the actual problem (and the kernel debug information assured me the components can be resolved) - but registering it fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone :-)